# Why does this method work with storyboard correctly, but not XIB?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface

The following method works with storyboard correctly, but for some reason doesn't work correctly for XIB. When I type one character in the searchfield it shows the searchResultsTableView frame at full screen instead of my custom frame. XIB will switch to my custom frame after two characters are typed. Storyboard shows my custom frame no matter what. What do I do in XIB to get this working?

```
  - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
  [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(77, 40, 240, 100)];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you make your XIB structure. Storyboard is just a group of XIB connected.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try writing that in the following UISearchDisplayController Delegate method instead-for example,

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
  didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { 
  [tableView.setFrame:CGRectMake(77, 40, 240, 100)];
}
```